# What happened to the gear icon in the reputation box of my profile?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

Today I noted a difference in *MyProfile* page, especially in *Activity* tab.

The top of the page contains the *Reputation*, *Badges* and *Impact* boxes. Until last week, in the *Reputation* box, an indication of "next one" was shown, but with the ability to click on a gear icon which switched the visualization to the reputation gained for a specific tag.

Now this icon disappeared. Please, what has changed? Is this information reachable from other locations?

[image]

Comment: For me, it is still visible: http://i.imgur.com/4xSVzk1.png

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot. No icon for me

Comment: It disappeared for me when I chose "track next privilege" (or whatever it was called) after reading this question.

Comment: It has vanished on me also.

Comment: @vhu this should explain why Glorfindel can still see it tracking their badge: I've also been tracking my privileges for a long time and the gear's gone anyway.

Comment: Is the downvote due to the lack of a hand-drawn red circle?

Comment: See [related post on MSE too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268269/245360).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if this was a feature then there wouldn't be a way to switch `badges->privileges` while forbidding `privileges->badges`...

Comment: @LucaDetomi This is certainly a bug - there is no way to get back to tracking tag badged once you have switched to privileges.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same bug.

Comment: Doh, fixing....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copy/pasting [my MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268316/3):

> This was completely my boneheaded fault by trying to only do a certain query if *reeaaally* necessary - well, it was really necessary after all :P
>
> A fix will be pushed out soon.

Comment: The gear is back:) I don't dare push it, lest I get stuck on the other side...

Comment: @AndrasDeak. , it works, **I tested it!**