# Missing toggle between next tag and next privilege

Tags: support

There was a toggle (gear icon) under the reputation graph, to the right of my next tag/privilege with the option to track one or the other.

I was tracking a tag and accidentally swapped it to privilege. That icon no longer appears so that I can change it back...

I think the button is normally just to the right of the progress bar, under the `.` in `5000 Rep.`

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this was [brought up earlier.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308461/whats-happend-to-gear-icon-in-reputation-box-of-myprofile) Still rather strange.